# Picking Same Color Probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So i recently came across this question,

**Marla has m bottles of marbles. Each bottle has n marbles of n different colours. Marla mixes all the marbles from all the bottles together. Now, she picks up n random marbles and puts them into another empty bottle.**

**Remember that now there can be more than one marble of a same colour in this bottle.
Marla picks up one marble from this bottle, notes down the colour and puts the marble back into the same bottle. The second time she picks up a marble from the same bottle, if it is of the same colour, then she succeeds.
What is the probability that she succeeds?**

This is a sample test case that was provided.

Eg. Sample Input

2 2

Sample Output

0.666666666666

Explanation

The probability of getting both the marbles in the bottle of the same colour is 0.33333333333333.

The probability of then succeeding is 1.

The probability of getting both the marbles in the bottle of different colours is 0.666666666666.

The probability of then succeeding is 0.5.

The total probabilty of succeeding is ( 0.333333333333 x 1 ) + (0.666666666666 x 0.5)= 0.666666666666

How do i go about this?
Probability is not my forte, so i am not really sure how to go about this.

I have made 3 cases (n=m),(n>m) and (n

Comment: You might want to take a look here http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question in order to improve your question, so that is has a better chance of being answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just consider the probability of getting a specific color of marble twice, and then, due to the symmetry of the problem, we may multiply by $n$ to get the total probability of success for Martha.

First, the probabilities of getting $k$ marbles of that color in your bottle: there are $nm$ marbles, and so there are $nm\choose n$ ways to pick $n$ marbles to put into a bottle.  Of those ways, there are $m\choose k$ ways to pick $k$ marbles from the $m$ marbles of the desired color, leaving ${nm-m}\choose {n-k}$ choices of other-colored marbles to fill up your bottle. So the probability of getting $k$ marbles of this color is:
$$\frac{{m\choose k}\cdot{nm-m\choose n-k}}{nm\choose n} $$
Now, given that you have $k$ marbles in your bottle, then the probability of picking one of those marbles is simply $k/n$. So your probability of getting $k$ marbles of one color and then picking that color of marble twice will be 
$$\frac{{m\choose k}\cdot{nm-m\choose n-k}}{nm\choose n}\cdot\frac{k^2}{n^2} $$
So your probability of success, multiplying by $n$ to account for all colors, is the sum of these probabilities for all possibilities of $k$, from 1 to $m$ or $n$, whichever comes first:
$$\Pr(Success)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)}\frac{{m\choose k}\cdot{nm-m\choose n-k}}{nm\choose n}\cdot\frac{k^2}{n} $$

...so yeah, as to a nice, closed form solution, I'm not too sure, but just going from counting equally likely events, I believe this would be your answer

Comment: [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+binom+%28m%2Ck%29+*+binom+%28%28n-1%29m%2Cn-k%29+k^2+for+k%3D0..n) says this is

$$
\frac mn\frac{\binom{m(n-1)}{n-1}}{\binom{mn}n}{}_3F_2(2,1-m,1-n;(n-1)(m-1)+1;1)\;.
$$

Comment: I have an objection about the quantity $\binom {mn}{n}$. Suppose we have $m = 3$ bottles and $n = 2$ marbles in each bottle (one black marble and one white). Thus, in the new bottle we have $6$ marbles, say $3$ white marbles and $3$ black ones. Let's say that from that bottle we want to take $2$ marbles. Your formula suggests that the ways to do so is $\binom 62=15$, but there are only $3$ ways to do so, i.e. $WW,WB,BB$. I assumed order does not count. Excuse me if I'm wrong or misunderstood any part of your thought.

Comment: @thanasissdr: We're interested in probabilities here, not ways. There are four equiprobable events, WW, WB, BW and BB. If you count WB and BW together as equiprobable with WW and BB, the result will be wrong.

Comment: @joriki Sure, but I have the impression that the formula $ \binom{n}{k}$ is used when we have to choose $k$ elements from $n$ *distinct* ones. Apparently, the $nm$ objects are not distinct. Isn't that the case?

Comment: @thanasissdr: Marla could perform the entire operation blindfolded. It follows that the probabilities can't depend on whether she can distinguish the marbles. Distinguishability matters when you're counting "different ways" of doing things and specify which "ways" you consider "different" -- it's irrelevant to probabilities (unless you're dealing with quantum theory, where distinguishability plays a more fundamental role than in the classical setting).

Comment: I wrote the code for the same and tried to submit, its giving wrong answer.
The thing is what about a case where suppose m=2 n=4
let the k colors be RBWG

There will also be cases where R1 (Denoting red from bottle 1)
R1R2B1B2 will be together right?
Is this case included in your formula?

Comment: @thanasissdr: This question can be decided experimentally: Put two objects of type A that you can't distinguish and another of type B in a bowl and draw two of them. Do you expect each of the "ways" AA and AB to be equiprobable? (If you do, I suggest you go and try it out :-)

Comment: @Paradox: Yes, this case is included in the formula, for $k=2$. Perhaps you're confused about the role of $k$? You write "let the $k$ colors be RBWG", but $k$ isn't the number of colours -- $n$ is the number of colours, and $k$ is the number of marbles of a given colour in the final bottle.

Comment: Sorry i meant let the n colors be. I know what k signifies.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce this formula even further? 
In combination form only.

Answer (score -1):

Total number of marbles are **mn**

Out of these **mn** marbles, m are of same colour. For our event to a success we need atleast 2 marbles of same colour.

We know $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$$

Hence the number of ways for selecting 2 marbles to be of same colour will be -
$$\binom{m}{2} *\binom{mn-m}{n-2} $$

So the probability of getting 2 marbles of the same color is

$$\frac{{m\choose 2}\cdot{mn-m\choose n-2}}{mn\choose n}$$

As we have 2 marbles in our bottle, the probability of picking one of those marbles is simply 2/n. So oour probability of getting 2 marbles of one color and then picking that color of marble twice will be

$$\frac{{m\choose 2}\cdot{mn-m\choose n-2}}{mn\choose n}\cdot\frac{2^2}{n^2}$$

To take into account all colours, we must multiply the result by n.

Hence, the probability for the event to be successfull is --

$$\frac{{m\choose 2}\cdot{mn-m\choose n-2}}{mn\choose n}\cdot\frac{2^2}{n}$$

Please correct me, if i am wrong. Its been a long time i came across probability questions.

Comment: You're only taking into account the one possibility that there are $2$ marbles of the colour in the bottle. There could be any number $k$ from $1$ up to $\min (m,n)$. Brent's answer correctly sums all the corresponding probabilities.

Comment: @joriki - thank you. :)