# Reduce Combination Formula

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Hey i have to write a code for this:
You can refer here: 
[Picking Same Color Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1368392/picking-same-color-probability/1368420#1368420)

For the entire question.

$\Pr(Success)=$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)}\frac{{m\choose k}\cdot{nm-m\choose n-k}}{nm\choose n}\cdot\frac{k^2}{n}$

The problem is that the values exceed standard long long limits and it overflows. This is a probability so i know the answer will never exceed 1.
How do i ensure my intermediate calculations don't overflow.
Is there a way i can reduce it down further?

Comment: Why do you have to write code for this?

Comment: I need it for a personal project of mine.

Comment: I've given you some hints, but I don't see why a personal project comes with **sample input and output**. If it's some homework or competition problem (ongoing) you should consider whether what you are doing is fair to others or not. By not stating the source of the problem you just make me suspicious. Sorry in advance if my suspicions are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{\binom{m}{k-1}\binom{x-m}{n-(k-1)}}{\binom{x}{n}} = \dfrac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{x-m}{n-k}}{\binom{x}{n}} \dfrac{?}{?}$. [Find the "?"s by looking at the factorial representations.]

When $k=n$, we have $\dfrac{\binom{m}{k}\binom{x-m}{n-k}}{\binom{x}{n}} = \dfrac{\binom{m}{n}}{\binom{x}{n}} = \dfrac{m!(x-n)!}{(m-n)!x!} = \prod_{i=1}^n \dfrac{m-n+i}{x-n+i}$.

From these two we can compute all the other coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

The binimial coefficients are individually huge, even though
your ratio is not. One method is to use 'zippering' or some
other method to do the rather massive cancellation. Or you might
take logs for intermediate steps and then exponentials at the
end.

In R the pdf and cdf of the hypergeometric distribution are
programmed to minimize overflow.

For example, suppose $m = 10,$ and $n = 12,$ and $k=5.$ Then in R you
could evaluate

$$\frac{{10\choose 5}{120-10 \choose 12-5}}{{120 \choose 12}}$$

in two ways:

```
 choose(10,5)*choose(120-10,12-5)/choose(120,12)
 ## 0.0007606184
 dhyper(5, 10, 120-10, 12)
 ## 0.0007606184
```

The first of these does not overflow for our choice of numbers,
but offers no protection against overflow. The second is programmed
to be more stable.

Then your sum might be computed in R as:

```
 m = 10;  n = 12;  k = 1:min(m,n)
 sum(dhyper(k, m, m*n-m, n)*k^2/n)
 ## 0.1526611
```

For larger numbers:

```
 m = 200;  n = 150;  k = 1:min(m,n)
 sum(dhyper(k, m, m*n-m, n)*k^2/n)
 ## 0.01325600
```

In the latter example, ${mn \choose n}$ overflows. For really huge numbers, you might try the parameter `log=T` in
the function `dhyper`.

You do not say what software you are using or what size numbers
you are trying to use. So I can't be sure how useful my specific examples are.
But I hope some of the ideas are useful.

Comment: Do you have anything c++/java/python specific?
I am really not sure about R and hyperfunction is not available in these languages.

Comment: Maybe python's scripy has hypergeometric. R is open source, so you could look at its code for dhyper. The other Answer gets at the idea of 'zippering'. And the idea of taking logs to tame the products should work in any language. Sorry I can't help with C++ or Java.

Comment: Scipy does have the hypergeometric pdf. Google it. I've never tried it, so can't vouch for how well it's protected against overflow. People I trust say python and family are very well programmed.